# Hide a field only in NewForm

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, newform

I have an SPO list for which I am using OOB forms.

I need to hide some fields in the `NewForm`, but show them in `EditForm`.

The list was created dynamically as mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308079/roadblocks-in-adding-fields-via-csom-in-spo).

However, I am in a bind on how to do it for an existing list.

If I click on `New` and hide the fields, it is being hidden from the `EditForm` as well.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Either you have to hide it by customizing list forms with Power Apps or using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PnP.PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/).

You can try below script to hide column only from New Form:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite -Interactive
$field = Get-PnPField -List "{ListUrl}" -Identity "{InternalNameOfColumn}"
$field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$field.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Below are the helper links to identify internal name of your column

- [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)